# Getting black square after merging two rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, merge

After merging two SRTM TIFF files all I get is a black rectangle.

Merged raster has zeros next to both black and white squares under layer name.

I have no clue what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

I downloaded 2 tiles from here: https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/Islands/

Tiles: S44E170 and S44E171

I opened both tiles in QGIS Desktop 3.4.3
[image]

[image]
[image]

And after merging them I get this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the _Symbology_ tab in the _Layer Properties_ window, with the _Min / Max Value Settings_ section expanded?

Comment: Take a look here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=merge+raster+black+%5Bqgis%5D+is%3Aquestion. For sure one of them is a duplicate. If not, edit the question to clarify. Tks.

Comment: I have edited my initial question to provide more detail description of my problem

Comment: Just tried exactly the same with your data and I cannot reproduce the issue. Only difference is that I'm using QGIS 3.4.2. However, you could try using `Built virtual raster` tool instead. Make sure to uncheck `Place each input file into a separate band`.

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue in QGIS 3.4.2 either, but when updating to 3.4.3 I found the same behavior. The log error says `GDAL command output:
0RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xa`. Seems like a problem with the numpy version. I can't found a solution for that yet, but it is already [reported](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20895). Please add the log of the gdal_merge gui to the question.

Comment: Just to let everyone know solution suggested by Gabriel De Luca worked for me. Many thanks Gabriel.

Comment: I have the same problem with merge and have spend the while morning trying to merge SRTM files in QGIS 3.4.3. I am using a Windows 64 bit machine. Answer No.2 did not work. I get an error message "ERROR: unknown command "version". So I am stuck with the same problem with no solution. Here is the traceback in QGIS 3.4.3. Processing algorithm… Algorithm 'Merge' starting… Input parameters: { 'DATA_TYPE' : 1, 'INPUT' : ['D:/GIS_Data/AU_SEHighlands/DEM30_SRTM/s35_e144_1arc_v3.tif','D:/GIS_Data/AU_SEHighlands/DEM30_SRTM/s35_e145_1arc_v3.tif','D:/GIS_Data/AU_SEHighlands/DEM30_SRTM/s35_e146_1arc_v3.ti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on a clean install of the *QGIS Standalone Installer Version 3.4*, on a 64-bit Windows 10 machine.

QGIS 3.4.3 seems to install a version of the *numpy* module that is not what *gdal_merge* needs.

After several attempts, I found this solution:

- *Run as Administrator* the *OSGeo4W.bat* file, located at the *QGIS 3.4* folder (*C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4* by default), that calls enviroment variables and opens a shell with administrator privileges
- run: `python -m pip show numpy`, returns `Version: 1.12.1+mkl`
- run: `python -m pip uninstall numpy`, agree to proceed, returns `Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.12.1+mkl`
- run: `python -m pip install numpy`, returns `Succesfully installed numpy-1.15.4`
- close the shell and run the *Merge* function in QGIS again, it will work fine now.

Comment: The discussion under this [bug report](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20895) implies that the issue wasn't caused by QGIS. But it sounds like you're saying that QGIS 3.4.3 *caused* the issue with the numpy version. If that's the case, please update the bug report and make sure the devs know that. Otherwise they won't know they need to fix it.

Comment: I see that they adjusted the category to _Build/Install_ . I do not have my credentials for that site at this time, but when I can I will clarify that the numpy module library was not installed separately from the QGIS distribution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you run these set of commands to reinstall numpy in case the first line above does not return a version:

After several attempts, I found this solution:

```
Run as Administrator the OSGeo4W.bat file, located at the QGIS 3.4 folder (C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4 by default), that calls enviroment variables and opens a shell with administrator privileges


run: python -m pip uninstall numpy, agree to proceed, returns Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.12.1+mkl

run: python -m pip install numpy, returns Succesfully installed numpy-1.15.4
```

I got merge grids to work again using the above commands.

Comment: Thank you, there was an error in the [other answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307195/getting-black-square-after-merging-two-rasters-in-qgis/307284#307284), the correct command was `python -m pip show numpy`. Already edited. Likewise, it is only to know the version of the installed module. The whole process can be reduced to run `python -m pip install -U numpy`, command that summarizes the module upgrade regardless of the installed version, as [reported](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/588) in OSGeo4W.